# Split image into N 100x100 px images (mosaic like)

Tags: jquery, html

I've an image with unknow size, and I need to:

- Crop it into a 4:5 image
- Split the cropped image into 20 images 1:1 that can be tailed in a 4x5 grid for compose the full image

I need to do the thing did in this jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j76Ke/

But I need to have a "background-image" with the part of image setted as propriety for each cell, so I'll can hide a single cell for show the background

I think something like:

```
.cell { background-image: url(data:mypartofimage); }
```

I can't set my background like in my fiddle because I need to hide a single cell and show the backgroud, that will be a dynamic content.

Any advice? (I can't use PHP or server side scripts)

EDIT: my fiddle is this now:
http://jsfiddle.net/LAWnx/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of applying a different background image to each cell, which you could kind of do with some JS... you can just use background colors on the cells.

```
.grid .cell  {
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.grid .cell:hover {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j76Ke/1/)

If you really wanted to apply a background to each cell, you would have to use some JS to calculate the offsets and apply them using [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position). It'll be the same image but different parts of it will show in each box.

Comment: I can't follow your first advice, because my grid will shows thumbnails of images, and on click on one of those, all cells will flip and will show the selected image. I need the second advice, but I've really not idea on how to calcuate if, because my image (as you can see in my example) is centered and cropped...

Comment: Hmm yeah that becomes tricky if its centered. Well, `imgWidth/2 - boxWidth/2` will give you the left edge of the image. Same with height for the top edge. From there, add `cellSize` to get top-left of next cell.

Comment: I made the script that set the background for each cell starting from the top left corner, I've added a new jsfiddle. How can i edit it for make it centered and 100% sized?

Comment: `background-size: auto 100%;` is responsible for the scaling. for the position, you'll need to calculate the left/top as I described in my previous comment. Start with that and then add 100 to the left 4 times, then reset the left and add 100 to top. It'd probably be easier to the cell divs in JS on the fly in a nested loop setup instead of trying to modify them.

Comment: I've already did the second part, but I can't add background-size: auto 100%; to each cell...